# $_POST not working with simple form

Tags: php, post

Don't really know why this is, but my simple PHP form is not working with the $_POST variable, returning an error.

HTML form:

```
<form name = "post" action = "insert_into.php" method = "post">
<p><label for="author">Author:</label></p><input type = "text" id = "author" name = "author"> 
<p><label for="subject">Subject:</label></p><input type = "text" id = "subject" name = "subject">
<p><label for="content">Content:</label></p><textarea id = "content" rows = "8" cols = "40" name = "content"></textarea>
<br />
<input type = "submit">
</form>
```

PHP processing script:

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];//line 7
$author = $_POST['author'];//line 8
$content = $_POST['content'];//line 9
$date = date("d/m/Y");
```

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: subject in E:\_temp\xampp\htdocs\sxp\insert_into.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: author in E:\_temp\xampp\htdocs\sxp\insert_into.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: content in E:\_temp\xampp\htdocs\sxp\insert_into.php on line 9
```

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: You have repeating `post` in `<form name = "post" action = "insert_into.php" method = "post">` might be what's making it act up. Try changing your form name to something else. Also, try to get rid of the extra spaces around the `=` signs.

Comment: Are the PHP and HTML pages separate or the same page? Have you read up on http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php?

Comment: @Fred uhhh...yep, that worked :D y u no answer with that?

Comment: If you can show us your entire process and form code, would help. The problem may lie in your headers.

Comment: @imulsion I posted it as an answer.

Comment: your code is fine, live demo: <http://codepad.viper-7.com/tcZ0nZ> use isset() to check if field is empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have repeating post in  might be what's making it act up. Try changing your form name to something else. Also, try to get rid of the extra spaces around the = signs.

Comment: @imulsion I noticed a similar problem earlier where an extra space which coincided with `$headers...` was at fault. Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: So you can't name a form `post`? Wacky. +1

Comment: @Jim I would suggest anything "but" `post`. PHP can be screwy that way, and some servers have that word reserved.